# Sidebar Doesn't appear in the bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am going through some video tutorial from newboston project but the sidebar doesn't appear on my browser and then I tried some other similar sidebar codes but it doesn't work. For other people it did worked but I have no clue why it isn't working for me. I tried different editors but no luck. Other bootstrap programs I could successfully run. Here is the link to the code can anyone tell me what could be the reason?

https://github.com/buckyroberts/Source-Code-from-Tutorials/tree/master/Bootstrap/sidebar

Comment: The issue is likely how you've set it up, not the code itself (especially if it works for others). Are you just downloading these files and opening the index? Or are you trying to implement it in your own code somewhere?

Comment: Your code seems ok. I have setup a working fiddle and when you click the sidebar collapses. Like Tom said, there must be something wrong with your setup. fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/973Lde7j/5/)

Comment: @Tom and grusl83 I am copying the code and trying to run the index.html. it worked in other editors like sublime and atom. I don't know why it doesn't work with the twitter bootstrap in webstorm.  The rest of the bootstrap programs worked fine. In this one the CSS code is written manually instead of bootstrap, could this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me, are you connected to the internet? You need to be on the internet so you can connect to the bootstrap and jquery CDN.

Make sure both files are in the same folder, otherwise it wont work.

I created a folder called sidebar and put the index.html and the sidebar.css file in it. Working correctly with Chrome.

Try copy and pasting the files from github, if you misspell the CDN for Jquery or bootstrap it wont work.

Comment: as I answered to the above comment I tried your way and it's fine but I don't know why it doesn't work in the webstorm while the files are saved as Twitter bootstrap..